# Spring HSQL Persistence of Complex Objects with Emums - Class with Classes with Enums - Auto persist

Tags: jpa, enums, spring-boot, persistence

that I want do persist a complex Object with Enums, I identified the Enums as cause of persistence problems, but haven't find a solutions.

User:

```
@Entity
@Data //lombok
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue()
private Long id;

private String username;

private String passwordHash;

private ArrayList<Role> roles; // <-- Problems by Persisting
}
```

Role:

```
@Data
public class Role implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private RoleDescription roleDescription;
private ArrayList<Authorization> authorizations = new ArrayList<Authorization>();
}
```

Role Description and Authorization are Enums

Database is enabled and Injected when role is null everything works flawless